# how do i stop duplicate data entry in array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with name validationValueIdValues so when user clicks on the input state ie. validationIdValue takes the value of individual input box. Now one user select on of option that is either Yes or No. The function creates an obj with key name equal to state, validationIdValue and value equal to users selection in short creates an obj like this

```
{08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b: "NO"}
```

Then this object is pushed to validationValueIdValues variable. Now problem arises when user select same box and changes select value from NO to YES

```
  {08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b: "YES"}
```

Then this object is pushed to the validationValueIdValues variable without checking if previous same obj with key exist or not and if exist then delete that obj from array. I am using following code for this purpose but some how duplicate obj still exist in an array.

```
  var validationValueIdValues = []  //as global variable

  if (this.state.selectedOption === "YES") {
    const attribute = {};
    attribute[this.state.validationIdValue] = "YES";
    if (validationValueIdValues.length > 0) {
      validationValueIdValues.forEach((data, index) => {
        if (Object.keys(data) == this.state.validationIdValue) {
          validationValueIdValues.splice(index, 1);
            validationValueIdValues.push(attribute);
        }
      });
    } else {
      validationValueIdValues.push(attribute);
    }
  }
```

I have used same if statement for `this.state.selectedOption === "NO"`

Comment: what are you trying to do. can you share code and requirement?

Comment: The number of validation id is fixed? or is it dynamically generated?

Comment: It is dynamically generated @VaibhavSingh

Comment: I am using jointjs in which inputs are dynamically generated as per users need each input has its own Id which reamin constant afterwards now when user selects this input I want to store id of input along with value of users input for type selection in an array @VahidAkhtar

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check all keys in the array to find the matching value. You don't need the code to be repeated for "YES" or "NO" as you mentioned. Something like this is generic enough to handle it

```
const validationValueIdValues = []  //as global variable


const addOrUpdateValidationValues = (newValidationValue) => {
    if(!newValidationValue) {
        return;
    }
    const keyOfNewValue = Object.keys(newValidationValue)[0]
    let added = false
    // loop through all values
    for(const validationValue of validationValueIdValues) {
        const keyOfCurrentValue = Object.keys(validationValue)[0]
        if(keyOfNewValue === keyOfCurrentValue) {
            // found that kind of key then just replace the value 
            added = true
            validationValue[keyOfCurrentValue] = newValidationValue[keyOfNewValue]
        }
    }
    // not added push
    if(!added) {
        validationValueIdValues.push(newValidationValue)
    }

}


// ...
// when you have the select or what ever event
// just call
addOrUpdateValidationValues(this.state.selectedOption)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if the value exists in the array, if exists update the value or push the new value.

```js
const array = [{'08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b': "YES"}, {'tyhgsgsvbb': 'NO'}];

const found = array.findIndex((item) => Object.keys(item).some(key => key === 'tyhgsgsvbb'));

if (found) {
  // toggle the value from yes to no, or vice versa
  array[found] = array[found] === 'YES' ? 'NO' : 'YES'
} else {
  array.push({newKey: 'newValue'});
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const newObject = {'08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b': "NO"}

const array = [{'08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b': "YES"}, {'tyhgsgsvbb': 'NO'}];

const items = array.filter(item => item['08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b'])

if(allKeys.length>0) array[array.findIndex(items[0])] =  newObject
else array[array.length] = newObject
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!

```
const array=[{'08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b': "YES"},{'08754d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b': "YES"}];
let newValue = {'08765d0f-2e7a-4fbd-9282-c38f5ddf8d8b': "YES"};

const index = array.findIndex(e=>Object.keys(e).indexOf(Object.keys(newValue)[0])>-1);
if(index > -1){
    array.splice(index,1,newValue); //Replacing the value
} else {
    array.push(newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'in' can be used to check for the key in array

```
// if key not in array then add to array
if ( !( 'mydata' in myArray) ) {
    myArray['mydata'] = 99;
}
```

Comment: The array is array of objects from what I understood. It will have indexes 0,1,2 (the keys will be 0,1,2)

Comment: Moreover 'in' is used to check if a given key is present inside object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: Indeed it is an array of object @ssBarBee